# How to get preprocessed code from Dev-c++ under Windows XP?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, dev-c++

How to get preprocessed C++ code from DevC++ under Windows XP? I've read about creating   `gcc -E file.cpp` file, but I still can't connect the dots, how to run this file? After I've compiled it everything went as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't *'run'* a preprocessed file. You can just **compile** and run it, or inspect it for what the preprocessor produced.

E.g. when using GCC you can run

```
gcc file.cpp -E <all preprocessor options as set from the IDE> -o file_preprocessed.cpp
```

to get the `file_preprocessed.cpp` file for inspection.

I don't know for the [dev-c++](/questions/tagged/dev-c%2b%2b) IDE in particular, but usually you'll get a representation of the actually used compiler flags of a project in the project settings somewhere.

Comment: I don't want run it I just want to see effects of preprocessing, mayby I should be more clear, could you give me any clues how to do this ?

Comment: See my comment on @zacaj's answer.

Comment: Dev-C++ has an option in Tools > Compiler Options... > General to add commands when calling the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

run

> gcc file.cpp -E -o file_preprocessed.cpp

then you can open file_preprocessed.cpp to see the output

Comment: run throught the console ?

Comment: @Qbik yes at least run it through console and ensure passing all (preprocessor relevant) options you have set in your IDE.